# Blazor Wasm Component Library for 3.2.0-preview2.20160.5

Tags: blazor, webassembly

I'm trying to build a reusable component library with a webassembly Blazor project built using the latest preview, 3.2.0-preview2.20160.5.

I first tried to add a Razor component library - however, since it targets .Net Core 3.1, whilst the Wasm project targets .Net Standard 2.1, that was a non-starter.

I tried to use the "blazorlib" template with the dotnet command line, but received a runtime error indicating the template wasn't compatible with the latest preview version.

I finally tried using a normal .Net Standard 2.1 class library. This will allow me to create .razor component files, and compiles fine. However, if I try to implement the code-behind in a separate file (eg a class called HelloWorldBase in HelloWorld.razor.cs for HelloWorld.razor), when I try to reference the component in the main Wasm project, the intellisense only suggests "HelloWorldBase" as the tag name, and the component does not produce any output. I suspect there is some kind of internal wiring that is missing.

Does anyone know the correct way please to go about creating a reusable Blazor component library with the latest preview version, that can be referenced in Wasm projects?

Many thanks

**Update 1**

Shown below is the structure of what I have currently in my component library (.Net Standard 2.1 Class Library project):

[image]

HelloWorld.razor:

```
@namespace BlazorPWA.Common.Components

@inherits HelloWorldBase

<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

HelloWorld.razor.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace BlazorPWA.Common.Components
{
    public class HelloWorldBase : ComponentBase
    {
    }
}
```

In the main project, with the component library referenced, intellisense is offering me both HelloWorld and HelloWorldBase, whereas with .razor components added directly to the main project, I'd only see the .razor filename:

[image]

Whether I choose HelloWorld, or HelloWorldBase, the component's output is not rendered, just a blank space.

My UserHome.razor (trying all 4 permutations of the component tag):

```
@page "/"

@namespace BlazorPWA.Portal.Views

@inherits UserHomeBase

Welcome to your new app.

UserId is <Observable>@UserStore.User?.UserId</Observable>

<button @onclick="IncrementUserId">Increment UserId</button>

<HelloWorld></HelloWorld>
<HelloWorldBase></HelloWorldBase>
<BlazorPWA.Common.Components.HelloWorld></BlazorPWA.Common.Components.HelloWorld>
<BlazorPWA.Common.Components.HelloWorldBase></BlazorPWA.Common.Components.HelloWorldBase>
```

Output and source - it can be seen that the component tags are just being output as if they are HTML tags:

[image]

To add a razor component to the main project, I'd do Add New Item --> Razor Component, whereas I do not have this option available in the component library - I have to add another file type, and then rename to .razor - I wonder if this is the problem, it's missing some templated/wire-up code?

Comment: "I first tried to add a Razor component library" - that was the correct choice. Whatever problem you saw should have been resolved another way.

Comment: The problem was/is that Blazor Wasm targets .Net Standard 2.1, whilst the Razor Component Library targets .Net Core 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I needed to use the dotnet CLI to add a new "razorclasslib" project. When added like this, instead of through the Visual Studio IDE, the project targeted .Net Standard instead of .Net Core, resolving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a `partial class`?

partial classes might not work in component libraries. I suggest you to make your code behind in a base class that your component inherits:

MyComponentBase.cs

```
public abstract class MyComponent : ComponentBase 
{
    protected void MyCodeBehindMethod()
    {
         ....
    }
}
```

MyComponent.razor

```
@inherits MyComponentBase

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
         MyCodeBehindMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not using partial classes, I've updated my question with more information